# Adding value from parent node

Tags: ruby, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to implement the [A* Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) to find the shortest path from A to B. I am using a linked list with nodes to find the best path.

One of the values I need to calculate is `g`, which is the cost of movement from the starting point to the current node. Moving horizontal or vertical cost `10`, and moving diagonal costs `14`.

For example,

```
11 22 33
44 55 66
```

Moving from `11` to `22` cost 10. From `22` to `66` cost 14, so moving from `11` to `66` cost 24 total according to that particular path.

In my node class, I have a method that calculate g from the previous node to the current node, in the previous example, `22` to `66`. In order to find the total `g` cost, I added the `g` value from the parent's node. However, this is extremely expensive and takes forever to run, especially when the number of possible paths is huge.

What can I do to speed up this algorithm? Is there a better way to calculate the `g` value?

Here is the relevant code from my Node class.

```
class Node 
    attr_accessor :position, :g, :h, :parent

    def initialize(position, parent = nil)
        @position = position
        @parent = parent
        if parent.nil?
            @g = 0
        else
            @g = calc_g + @parent.g #<= this line costs the issue. 
        end
    end

    def calc_h(end_pos)
        (@position.first - end_pos.first).abs + (@position.last - end_pos.last).abs
    end

    def calc_g
        row_diff = (@position.first - self.parent.position.first).abs
        col_diff = (@position.last - self.parent.position.last).abs
        if [row_diff, col_diff] == [1,1]
            g = 14
        else
            g = 10
        end

    end

end
```

Here is my `MazeSolver` class.

```
require_relative 'node'

class MazeSolver

    attr_accessor :open_list, :closed_list, :maze, :start_node, :end_node, :current_node

    def initialize(file_name)
        @open_list = []
        @closed_list = {}
        @maze = create_maze_array(file_name)
        @start_node = Node.new(find_point("S"))
        @end_node = Node.new(find_point("E"))
        @current_node = @start_node
    end

    def create_maze_array(file_name)
        maze = File.readlines(file_name).map(&:chomp)
        maze.map! do |line|
            line.split('')
        end

        maze
    end

    def find_point(sym)
        @maze.each_with_index do |line, row|
            line.each_with_index do |el, col|
                return [row, col] if el == sym
            end
        end
    end

    def find_neighbors(position)
        row, col = position

        (row-1..row+1).each do |r|
          (col-1..col+1).each do |c|
                next if @closed_list.values.include?([r, c])
                unless @maze[r][c] == '*'
                    @open_list << Node.new([r, c], @current_node)
                end
            end
        end
        @open_list
    end

    def solved?
        @current_node.position == @end_node.position
    end

    def solve
        until solved?
            @closed_list[@current_node] = @current_node.position

            find_neighbors(@current_node.position)
            @current_node = lowest_f(@open_list)
            @open_list.delete(@current_node)
        end
        path = get_path(@current_node)
        display_route(path)
    end

    # determine the lowest f score node
    def lowest_f(nodes)
        f_score = {}
        nodes.each do |node|
            f_score[node] = node.g + node.calc_h(@end_node.position)
        end
        f_score.sort_by { |node, score| score }.first.first
    end

    # create path array
    def get_path(node)
        path = []
        until node.position == @start_node.position
            path << node.position
            node = node.parent
        end
        path
    end

    # display maze without route and maze with route
    def display_route(path)
        display_maze
        path.each do |move|
            unless @maze[move.first][move.last] == 'E'
                @maze[move.first][move.last] = 'X'
            end
        end
        puts 
        display_maze
    end

    # display the maze as it is.
    def display_maze
        @maze.each do |line|
            puts line.join
        end
    end

end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  puts "What is the name of the maze file?"
  begin
        MazeSolver.new(gets.chomp).solve
    rescue
        puts "File does not exist. Try Again"
        retry
    end
end
```

Here is the link to [repl](https://repl.it/EPka/28) with example mazes that I worked with. `maze1.txt` is the one that takes a long time to run.

Comment: Can't you store `g` in the node as you traverse?  That way you only have to add to the previous node to 10 or 14 for the current node?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do, by just adding `@parent.g`? Is that not right?

Comment: Yeah sorry.  For some reason I got the impression G was being recalculated.

Comment: seems like g might be recalculated for some reason. If i run this with a 10 by 15 grid maze, the program takes about a minute to run.

Comment: What does your engine look like?

Comment: I updated the question with all of my code.